# How to make a producer-consumer code with OpenMP?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, task, openmp

I'm trying to make a single thread (master), in an OpenMP C code, continuously work in a single operation (which is to produce tasks) while the others (slaves) wait for the tasks produced by the master to work on. Is it possible to make the master thread work only on it's specific task, without having other tasks scheduled to it?

The purpose of this, is to have a single thread, communicating all the time with an external device and producing tasks to be executed by the other threads.

Here is an example of what I'm trying:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp master
    {
        printf("MASTER START\n"); fflush(stdout);
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
            #pragma omp task
            {
                printf("[Thread %d] working on task %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i);
                fflush(stdout);
            }
        }
        printf("MASTER END\n"); fflush(stdout);
    }
}
```

Executing the code above with two threads, I get something like this:

```
MASTER START
...
[Thread 1] working on task 998
[Thread 0] working on task 999
...
MASTER END
[Thread 1] working on task 694
[Thread 0] working on task 696
...
```

Which clearly shows that the master thread is working in the tasks it created before it finished its work. That's what I want to avoid. Master thread should work exclusively on it's work before helping the others on the tasks.

Note: I know OpenMP specification says tasks may be executed right as they are created (by the creator) instead of going to the queue. So maybe I cannot use tasks directives to achieve the result I want? Is there any other way to do that with OpenMP?

**EDIT**

Just to clarify why I want master thread NOT to work on the tasks: Master thread, in my application, is responsible for sending tasks to GPU and receiving results. Some of the work that is not done at GPU is them delegated to the CPU threads (in the form of omp tasks, for now). If master thread starts working on the CPU tasks, them it won't communicate with GPU and GPU will be idle.

The compiler I'm using is nvcc 10.0.130 and gcc 8.2.1

Comment: Use a thread safe queue from, say, TBB to set up a producer-consumer system using busy waiting?

Comment: @Richard Thanks for commenting. It would be a nice option, but if I had to abandon OpenMP, I think I would use Pthreads directly. Maybe having semaphores to control the producer-consumer mechanism. But I would like to continue using OpenMP, for simplicity.

Comment: Why do you care if things are getting done? Typically it is the right thing that the master executes some of the tasks if the task queue is filling up and no thread is available. What is the reason you do not want to exploit that? Also note that this is generally implementation dependent, so you should add your implementation and version.

Comment: @Zulan I don't want master thread to work on the tasks because it needs to be 100% dedicated to talking with an external device (which is a GPU). If master starts working on CPU tasks, it won't be able to keep a live connection to GPU, sending work to it as soon as it finishes the previous work, which would be a wast of computational resource (in my application).

Comment: What would happen in your envisioned application if all workers are busy and CPU tasks aren't getting done? Would that impact performance?

Comment: @Zulan No, because what dictates the execution time is the GPU work (task on CPU are just leftovers from GPU, to get a little more speedup).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is a bit longer than practically necessary, please make sure to read it all. I wanted to include also the theoretical parts, which unfortunately don't matter practically.

Generally, OpenMP gives a lot of freedom about the execution to the implementation. This can allow optimizations in the implementation - and I encourage you to do the same: Allow the implementation - compiler & library - to do what it thinks is best while giving it the most information possible. At the same time, measure the performance end-to-end and with tools that understand OpenMP. Try to understand what actually happens, rather than rely *only* on your intuitive understanding what's optimal.

OpenMP 4.5 gives you one way to tell kind-of the compiler what you want - task priorities. i.e.

```
#pragma omp single
{
    #pragma omp task priority(10)
    {
        printf("MASTER START\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        {
            #pragma omp task priority(0)
            {
                    printf("[Thread %d] working on task %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i);
```

As per the standard, tasks with a higher numerical priority value are recommended to execute before lower priority ones. This is only a **hint** and the implementation is free to ignore this.

The freedom given by the standard also allows [lazy impementations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46601207/620382). `libgomp` (gcc's OpenMP library), for instance, has [a hard-coded logic](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/fbd263526ad105a953fd51d9f7bca2c3f268cf82/libgomp/task.c#L388) to immediately execute all spawned tasks if there are more than 64 queued tasks per thread. I don't believe the priority matters in the decision to defer a task or not, only for queued tasks.

Which you can observe using something like this:

```
int task_count = 1;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp single
    {
        printf("MASTER START (%d)\n", omp_get_thread_num());
        fflush(stdout);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        {
            #pragma omp atomic
            task_count++;
            #pragma omp task
            {
                int q;
                #pragma omp atomic capture
                q = task_count--;
                printf("[Thread %d] working on task %d (%d queued)\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i, q);
```

You could use that information to prevent spawning tasks in the first place if there are too many tasks in flight already. Now you say, it doesn't matter if CPU tasks aren't getting done. I doubt that, somehow they have to eventually complete. So you may want to avoid spawning too many CPU tasks anyway. Unfortunately you end up with a implementation-specific solution that is based on understanding of how this implementation works. On the other hand, it will probably also help with the other major OpenMP library used by Intel/clang. It is up to you to figure out if this is a better solution than rolling out your own tasks queue management - be it on top of OpenMP, pthreads, tbb or whatever.